# Is there a numpy function to compress a (k, m, n) matrix to a (k//2, m//2, n//2) matrix by summing neighbors?

Tags: python, numpy

This can be accomplished with

```
cube = (
    cube[::2, ::2, ::2]
    + cube[1::2, ::2, ::2]
    + cube[::2, 1::2, ::2]
    + cube[1::2, 1::2, ::2]
    + cube[::2, ::2, 1::2]
    + cube[1::2, ::2, 1::2]
    + cube[::2, 1::2, 1::2]
    + cube[1::2, 1::2, 1::2]
)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a function to accomplish this quickly and cleanly. If not, is there a canonical name for this operation?

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097941/strided-convolution-of-2d-in-numpy).  This dealt with 2D, but the general Scipy convolve would work in place of the convolve2d used in some of the answers.  block_reduce as suggested by ShlomiF is cleaner though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a classical strided-convolution pooling operation.
You can do this in many ways, but the most straightforward would probably be to use skimage's `block_reduce` functionality, as so -

```
from skimage.measure import block_reduce
a = np.arange(6*8*4).reshape(6, 8, 4)
reduced_a = block_reduce(a, block_size=(2, 2, 2), func=np.sum) 
# Make sure the dimensions are as expected:
print(reduced_a.shape)
# (3, 4, 2)

# Test specific value for correct reduction of matrix:
assert reduced_a[0, 0, 0] == np.sum(a[:2, :2, :2])
# And more generally, for any index:
i, j, k = 2, 0, 1
assert reduced_a[i, j, k] == np.sum(a[i*2:i*2+2, j*2:j*2+2, k*2:k*2+2])
```

Another way would be to directly convolve your "cube" with a "ones" kernel, and then subsample for the required 2-stride:

```
from scipy import ndimage
convolved_a = ndimage.convolve(a, np.ones((2, 2, 2)))[::2, ::2, ::2]
# Assert that this is indeed the same:
assert np.all(convolved_a == reduced_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In purely `numpy` (say, if you're trapped in a non-extensible API, or are otherwise trying to limit dependencies), you can use my recipe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960192/using-numpy-as-strided-function-to-create-patches-tiles-rolling-or-sliding-w)

```
cube = np.sum(window_nd(cube, 2, 2), (-3, -2, -1))
```